# General rule of sequence $1,11,21,1211,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I understand that a term is the same as the "reading" of the previous one. The second term is equal to 1 amount of 1  in the first term = 11. The third term is equal to amount of 1 in the second term 1 = 21.
Is there any way to deduce a general rule?

Comment: Do you mean you want a formula for the nth term?

Comment: [This sequence is pretty famous, actually.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)

Comment: I think this problem is still unsolved

Comment: The late, great John Conway gave an asymptotic in terms of the unique positive root of a degree 71 polynomial. [Have a look.](http://www.njohnston.ca/2010/10/a-derivation-of-conways-degree-71-look-and-say-polynomial/)

Comment: @Integrand That's actually insane. Both Conway and Mathematics never cease to amaze me